# Форма Symfony: как передать массив?

Tags: symfony, doctrine2, doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-orm

Даны три сущности Doctrine.
**Ответы на вопросы анкеты `Answer`**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AnswerRepository")
 */
class Answer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Options", inversedBy="answers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $options;

    public function getOptions(): ?options
    {
        return $this->options;
    }

    public function setOptions(?options $options): self
    {
        $this->options = $options;

        return $this;
    }
    // ...
}
```

**Варианты ответов на вопросы анкеты `Options`**:

```
class Options
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="options")
     */
    private $answers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->answers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Answer[]
     */
    public function getAnswers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->answers;
    }

    public function addAnswer(Answer $answer): self
    {
        if (!$this->answers->contains($answer)) {
            $this->answers[] = $answer;
            $answer->setOptions($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAnswer(Answer $answer): self
    {
        if ($this->answers->contains($answer)) {
            $this->answers->removeElement($answer);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($answer->getOptions() === $this) {
                $answer->setOptions(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
    // ...
}
```

*И сущность с вопросами анкеты Question.*
Отправляю POST-запрос с ID вариантов ответов на вопросы анкеты:

```
{
    "options": [
        "1",
        "2"
    ],
}
```

Таким образом:

```
$answer = new Answer();
   $form = $this->createFormBuilder($answer)
        ->add('options', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Options::class,
            'multiple' => true
        ]);
```

Получают ответ:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Expected argument of type \"App\\Entity\\Options or null\", \"Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\" given at property path \"options\"."
}
```

dev.log:

```
[2019-07-05 15:16:25] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: "Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Options or null", "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" given at property path "options"." at C:\xampp\htdocs\suppliers\src\vendor\symfony\property-access\PropertyAccessor.php line 197 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\PropertyAccess\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Expected argument of type \"App\\Entity\\Options or null\", \"Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\" given at property path \"options\". at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\suppliers\\src\\vendor\\symfony\\property-access\\PropertyAccessor.php:197)"} []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать коллекцию для указания типа в форме. Подробней можете почитать в [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html).

```
$builder
    ->add('options', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => EntityType::class,
        'entry_options' => [
            'class' => Options::class,
            'choice_label' => 'id',
        ],
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'required' => false,
    ]);
```

ps. Лучше не использовать в наименовании сущностей множественного числа. Т.е. должно быть вот так:

```
class Option
```

Соответственно и наименование переменных в зависимости от того в единственном или множественном числе они (answers, option).

Comment: Спасибо! К сожалению, doctrine говорит о том, что `Option is reserved class name`

Comment: @ОлегНечаев тогда можно в классе указать наименование для доктрины. `name="\`option\`"`. Обратите внимание на кавычки - \`.